# Cannot import Appengine modules in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, compiler-errors

In my Eclipse project (GWT) I am trying to import the modules below, in order to add some Blobstore code.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.files.FileService;
import com.google.appengine.api.files.FileServiceFactory;
```

I don't get any error or warning from the Eclipse build function. Nevertheless, when I do "GWT compile" from Eclipse, I get the error messages below:

```
[ERROR] Line 3: The import com.google.appengine.api.files cannot be resolved
[ERROR] Line 4: The import com.google.appengine.api.files cannot be resolved
```

How can I sort it out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot reference non-client code from your GWT client. Remember that your GWT client code will be compiled to Javascript, so any references to actual Java can't be compiled out.

Make sure any reference to the blobstore api is done in server code, not client. Those imports should never be necessary in code that must be compilable to javascript.